# Pagination for rails api and react api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, pagination, rails-api

I am building a web app. For that I am using `rails` as api for `backend`. Also using `react` for `frontend`. I have a model `user`. I would like to display all the `users` along with its details to the website users. So I have around 10,000 + users. So I can't send all the users atonce to the frontend. I would like to display only 50 users at a time. So to see next 50 users the frontend will send me a new request to get the next 50 users and so on. So I am not getting correct path how to build it.

Now I am fething all the users like this and my server is getting hang.

my `users_controller.rb`

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
      users = User.all
      render_success(:ok, users, meta: { message: 'User sucessfully send' })
    end
 end
```

In brief -  I want to send only limited number of data to frontend in each request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `gem 'kaminari'` for pagination in rails.
Fetching users based on page number:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def index
  per_page = PAGINATION[:users] # you can define it in app_config.yml  
  users = User.page(params[:page]).per(per_page)
  render json: { user_list: users, per_page: per_page, user_count: users.count, success: true }, status: :ok
end
```

end

In react you can use `react-paginate` to render paginate block.

You can render this in User Index screen

```
    renderPaginateBlock = () => {
    const { user_count, per_page } = this.props;
    if (user_count > per_page) {
      return (
        <div align='center'>
          <ReactPaginate
            previousLabel={"<"} nextLabel={">"} marginPagesDisplayed={2}
            pageRangeDisplayed={5} pageCount={this.props.user_count/this.props.per_page}
            onPageChange={(data) => this.getUserWithPagination(data.selected + 1)}
            containerClassName={"pagination custom"} subContainerClassName={"pages pagination"}
            activeClassName={"active"}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

This is to set current_page and access the API:

```
getUserWithPagination = (activePageNo) => {
    const { fetchUsers } = this.props;
    fetchUsers(activePageNo)
  }
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`limit`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/limit) and [`offset`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/offset), here is an **example**, it's pretty simple and doesnt require any libs:

Rails code:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def users
  users = User.limit(params[:limit]).offset(params[:offset])
  render json: { users: users }
end
```

React code:

```
const PER_PAGE = 50  // How much users to load
export default class Users extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      offset: 0,
      limit: PER_PAGE,
      users: []
    }
    this.handlePageClickNext = this.handlePageClickNext.bind(this)
    this.handlePageClickPrev = this.handlePageClickPrev.bind(this)
  }
  loadUsersFromServer() {
    fetch(`/users?limit=${this.state.limit}&offset=${this.state.offset}`)
      .then(response => response.json()).then(response => {
      this.setState({ users: response.users })
    })
  }
  handlePageClickPrev() {
    // Load prev 10 users
    let offset = this.state.offset - PER_PAGE
    if (offset < 0) return 
    this.setState({offset: offset}, () => {
      this.loadUsersFromServer();
    });
  };
  handlePageClickNext() {
    // Load next 10 users
    let offset = this.state.offset + PER_PAGE
    if (offset >= this.state.total) return

    this.setState({offset: offset}, () => {
      this.loadUsersFromServer();
    });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    // Load users on start
    this.loadUsersFromServer();
  }
  render() {
     const users = this.state.users.map((u)=> {
       return <li>{u.id}</li>
     })

    return (
     <div>
       <ul>
        {users}
       </ul>
       <button onClick={this.handlePageClickPrev}>Prev</button>
       <button onClick={this.handlePageClickNext}>Next</button>
     </div>
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you set the this.state.total in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help you. But you can use will_paginate gem,

```
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
```

in your index function use

```
@users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
```

Using this you'll get all the users sent in one request and paginated